# Select Insert subquery from C# windows form in sqlserver table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on Inventory software for purchase sale of Products. I want to get profit loss after purchase and sale. Purchase form is working correctly. Now i want to sale a product from sale form and want to get purchase invoice Number where in hand quantity is greater than 0 and against each datagridview row item name for profit lose. So please suguest me how i how defined sub query in insert command which get Pur_Invoice_No from purchase table .
given below query is generating double values error.

Sale Form
[image: This is my Form]

Purchase Table

[image: Purchase Table]

```
Sale_Invoice_No Item_Code   Item_Batch_No   Item_Pur_InvoiceNo  Item_Sale_Quantity  Item_Unit_RetailPrice   Sale_Item_Discount  Item_Discount_Amount
```

1   1           1   5   1   5
1   2

```
 try
            {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mateenwin;User ID=sa;Password=123");
                conn.Open();

                    SqlCommand commandd = new SqlCommand("Select max(Sale_Invoice_No) from Sale", conn);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()))
                {
                    InvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(1);

                }
                else
                {
                    int tig =Convert.ToInt32( 1);

                    InvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(commandd.ExecuteScalar()) +tig;
                }
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in saved.dataGridView1.Rows)
                {


                    if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
                    int batch = 1;
                    for(int i=0;i>batch;i++)
                    {

                    }

                    SqlConnection cons = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mateenwin;User ID=sa;Password=123");

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into Sale (Sale_Invoice_No,Payment_Type_ID,Customer_ID,Sale_Reference,Sale_Remarks,Item_Code,Item_Sale_Quantity,Item_Unit_RetailPrice,Sale_Item_Discount,Item_Discount_Amount,Item_Payable_Amount,Cash_Received,Return_Amount,Login_ID,User_ID,Item_Pur_InvoiceNo,Sale_Entry_Date)Values ('" + InvoiceNo + "','" + saved.comboBox1.SelectedValue + "','" + saved.comboBox2.SelectedValue + "','" + saved.textBox3.Text + "','" + saved.textBox4.Text + "','" + row.Cells[6].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[1].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[2].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[3].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[4].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + saved.textBox10.Text + "','" + saved.textBox11.Text + "','" + saved.comboBox3.SelectedValue + "','" + this.comboBox2.SelectedValue + "',(Select DISTINCT Pur_Invoice_No IN (Select DISTINCT Pur_Invoice_No from Purchase where Purchase.Item_Code ='" + row.Cells[6].EditedFormattedValue + "')),  GetDate())", cons);

                    cons.Open();


                    using (cons)
                    {

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
                MessageBox.Show("Invoice successfully Saved");
```

Comment: [Beware of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: what you mean of little bobby tables

Comment: Please don't take that the wrong way but if you can't search the net and find that out yourself then you should ask yourself can you be a programmer. The most important skill of a programmer today is being able to find stuff on the net.